# Ember.js Computed property does not update hasMany item after sorting

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following setup for displaying my order by date:
[image: orders by day]

I have the following template that shows each order for a given week: (I stripped some html for brevity)

**Template**:

```
{{#each ordersByDate in ordersByDateOfWeek}}
    <div class="orders-by-date">
        <div>
            <span>{{order-date-formatted ordersByDate.date}}</span>
        </div>

        {{#each order in ordersByDate.orders}}
            {{order.number}} {{! updates correctly}}
            {{order.market.name}} {{! a hasmany property called here, does not update}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}
```

The **computed property**:

```
ordersByDateOfWeek: function () {

    var result = []; // return value
    var object = null
    var date = null;


    // add every order to an array with a date an order objects
    this.forEach(function (order) {

        // get the date of the order 
        date = order.get('created');

        // create a new object that holds the orders for a given date
        object = result.findProperty('date', date);

        // create the object if it does not exist
        if (!object) {
            object = {
                date: date,
                orders: [],
                // some more
            };

            // add the object with the date to the result
            result.push(object);
        }

        // add the orders to the current object
        object.orders.push(order);

        // more calculations done here below
    });
}.property('model', 'sortProperties', 'sortAscending'),
```

What it does is, that it creates an array of objects like this:

```
[
   {
     "date":"2014-12-08",
     "orders":[// order objects here],
     // some more properties
   },
   {
     "date":"2014-11-08",
     "orders":[],
   },
   {
     "date":"2014-10-08",
     "orders":[],
   },
]
```

I am trying for hours now, and cannot get my head around it to get it to work. My intuition says that it has to do with promises? But in the `"orders: []"` array are real Ember objects, so it should have to work I think.

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks guys!

Edit: to be 100% clear: my order model consists solely of orders. That custom object do I create myself. Thats why the binding of data gets broken I think.

Comment: Have you checked out `Ember.computed.sort`? Also there's a standard property `arrangedContent` that is used as the result of a sort if you're looking for that sort of thing.

Comment: Hi, I am a bit late, but thanks for your answer! However I do not see how this will work because `arrangedContent` is also used for `sortProperties` which I already use. See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_arrangedContent Do I have to write my own `arrangedContent` with my own sorting build in? If you provide an working example in an answer I will accept it as such.

Comment: After days of fiddling with it I do a bounty on it. I can't get where I want, because arranged content does not have the possibility to have a date before the original items.

Comment: @DelphiLynx could you, please, share your fiddle so that we can work with a base  ?

Comment: A jsbin/jsfiddle would definitely be helpful...

Comment: as said by others we need more code likely what does your model look like...

Comment: It is already fixed by the complete answer of @Lazybensch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your template only updates itself when `ordersByDateOfWeek` updates. Which happens whenever any of its watched properties changes (`'model', 'sortProperties', 'sortAscending'`). When you build order objects yourself, under the hood ember will add them as you want but they will not cause the `ordersByDateOfWeek` to update and hence your template will not recognise the change.

The easiest solution would be to work with actual properties, (i.e. your orders models) and add them with `'model.@each.orders'` to  `ordersByDateOfWeek`s watch list. If you need extra fields like `date` create them as computed properties on the model, like so:

```
date: Ember.computed.alias('created')
```

You should rarely need to create objects by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. A bit late, however I was not on the project last time. Your answer did the trick, I have edited the watch list of the computed properties, and added `model.@each`. (orders is not a has-many in my case)

Answer (score 2):

Computed properties are not magic ;-) They are great, but not magic.

I suspect that since you are listening on changes for `'model'`, it does not trigger the update when you change properties nested inside this object. Your property will only be re-evaluated when the object reference `'model'` gets changed.

In this case you need at least `'model.@each.orders'` if you actually assign a new Array to your objects. If you just change the array by adding more objects later on, you need a two step solution. If this is the case, write a comment and I will expand my answer.

For reading: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Comment: I have to add that my model consists solely of orders. That custom date I put in front is my own implementation to show the data as shown in the image. (I will add this information to the question too)